# Spell checking (but not correction) in NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'd like to have an NSTextView alert a user to misspelled words (eg with a red underline), but not automatically correct them. In my use case, I just want the user alerted to misspelled words, but there are enough cases where words will be spelled incorrectly that I don't want it correcting for them.

I've seen the `Continuous Spell Checking` (which, when I tested it, performed correction, not just checking), and `Automatic Spelling Correction` (which doesn't seem to do much of anything). Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `continuousSpellCheckingEnabled` and `automaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled` are properties of `NSTextView`, not `NSTextField`. How did you test them?

Comment: Oops, I meant NSTextView. In the code I'm looking at the variable is named textfield, so I got confused. I've updated the question.

Comment: I tested by setting the values in IB and rerunning.

Comment: The settings are overruled by the system prefs. Try setting them in code.

Comment: Thanks, that works!  If you submit this as an answer with a little more explanation I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spelling and Grammar settings in the NIB are overruled by the Text settings in the Keyboard System Preferences. The settings can be changed in code when the view is loaded. The user can change the settings at runtime with Spelling and Grammar in the Edit menu or the Context menu (if available).